# Select2 with tags and suggestions

Tags: jquery-select2

I was using Select2 to have a list of brands and categories, each grouped by `<optgroup>`.

So far so good, because the list was not changing. Now I have to implement a Product search, which will have no specific values, so you can search for everything you type in.

For example, if the user types in "sho", i want to have:

```
**Products**
 - sho (exactly what the user enters)

**Brands** (suggestions from a list)
 - Adidas Shoes
 - Nike Shoes

**Categories** (suggestions from a list)
 - Shoes for women
 - Shoes for men
```

And as the user types more characters, the `sho` under `Products` keeps updating to show what they entered.

The code for the previous version was:

```
<select id="search_bar">
    <option></option>
    <optgroup label="Stores">
        {% for merchant in all_merchants %}
            <option value="{% url %}">{{ merchant.display_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Categories">
        {% for category in all_categories %}
            <option value="{% url %}">{{ category.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

I tried enabling tags, by doing `tags: true`, and it works but not entirely, because if I type in something that matches a brand or a category, the tag will disappear. I.E, if i type "Adidas", it will show only the Adidas under brands (so if i click it, I'm taken to the brand page), but not as a tag that i can click and be taken to the product search page.

Does that make sense?

Comment: it misses the js script wit hthe creation of select2.. and what is a line `{% for merchant in all_merchants %}`  is it select2?

Comment: the process is normal if tag exist in Adidas, there is no sense to propose to add new tag since it exists...

Comment: You lost me there. Don't worry about the {% for %}, that's django and that part works well populating brands and categories. 

The problem is the free input, I don't want users to type "adidas" and the tag disappearing and showing only the suggestion. I need the tag to stay all the time.

Comment: if the answer resolves your problem, dont forget to close the answer by validating and upvoting

Answer (score 0):

Ok its first try, i you click on new tag to create, i keep it in the list of firstdropdown and you have propagation in the second dropdown (at least 2 character minimun):

```js
$('#source').select2({
 tags:true
});
$('#search').select2({
  tags:true,
  insertTag:function (data, tag) {
      data.push(tag);
    },
  createTag: function (params) {
      return {
        id: params.term,
        text: params.term,
        newTag: true
      }
    },

  matcher: matchCustom,
}).on("select2:select", function(e) {

//    if( e.params.data.newTag){
        select2_search($("#source"), e.params.data.text);
        $(this).find('[value="'+e.params.data.id+'"]').replaceWith('<option selected value="'+e.params.data.id+'">'+e.params.data.text+'</option>');
//    }
        //uncomment if you want to play the same search
      //$("#search").val("0").trigger("change");
});


function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }


    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return null;
}

function select2_search ($el, term) {
  $el.select2('open');
  
  // Get the search box within the dropdown or the selection
  // Dropdown = single, Selection = multiple
  var $search = $el.data('select2').dropdown.$search || $el.data('select2').selection.$search;
  // This is undocumented and may change in the future
  
  $search.val(term);
  $search.trigger('input');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select id ="search" class="myselect" style="width:50%;"  >
       <option value="0"></option>      
</select>        <prev><== Type new tag into search</prev>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<select style="width:100%;" id="source" multiple="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">   

   <optgroup class="select2-result-selectable" label="Brand"   >  

      <option value="Adidas shoes">Adidas shoes</option>                          
      <option value="Pantalon">Pantalon</option>     
      <option value="short">short</option>  
   </optgroup> 

   <optgroup class="select2-result-selectable" label="Categories" >                
      <option value="Shoes for men">Shoes for men</option>
      <option value="Shoes for women">Shoes for women</option>     
      <option value="Other things for wommen">Other things for women</option>     
      <option value="Other things for men">Other things for men</option>        
  </optgroup>                                                    
</select>
```